# python selenium find element is slow

Tags: python, selenium, performance, google-chrome, driver

```
<body>
    <tbody id="data-table">
       <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</body>
```

I need a fast way to find the texts contained within each `<td>`

I tried

```
main_table = driver.find_element(By.ID, "data-table")
for i in range(3):
     main_table.find_element(By.XPATH, "tr[" + str(i + 1) + "]/td[1]").text
     main_table.find_element(By.XPATH, "tr[" + str(i + 1) + "]/td[2]").text
     main_table.find_element(By.XPATH, "tr[" + str(i + 1) + "]/td[3]").text
```

this is incredibly slow... nearly 200ms for each search
this simple loop takes over 3 x 3 x 200 ms or 1.8 sec

the actual data I need to extract is even bigger, its over 100 `tr` and each having 5 `td`
this takes over 100 secs to complete

is there a faster way to do this?

I was wondering if there is a way to just extract all the tags under the main table for example

```
extracted_data = main_table.get_all_tags()
for tr in extracted_data:
    for td in tr:
        print(td.text)
```

the idea is we extract all the sub-tags data and then use pure python to further extract the sub data instead of crawling it using `find_element`

Comment: are you just looking for the text in each td tag?

Comment: why are you using range for loops? you should iterate over every row. something like `for row in main_table.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr")` And then extract td for every row.

Comment: @EJoseph yes, I just need the fastest possible way to get the text in each td tag
@AlbinPaul The problem I had it seems that `main_table.find_element(By.XPATH, "tr[" + str(i + 1) + "]/td[1]").text` is equivalent to `driver.find_element(By.ID, "data-table").find_element(By.XPATH, "tr[" + str(i + 1) + "]/td[1]").text`

Comment: this called the whole function twice thus slowing things down, Im trying to just cache the whole subtags under the primary id and not use find element again

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the text in each td tag you could do:

```
main_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="data-table"]/tr/td')
for xin main_table:
   print(x.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify the table element and get the `outerHtml` of the table element first, Then use pandas to read the html

```
main_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[.//tbody[@id='data-table']]").get_attribute("outerHtml")
df=pd.read_html(main_table)[0]
print(df)
```

Import following library

```
import pandas as pd
```

If pandas,not installed then install it first

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: I will try this and get back as soon as possible